# Implementation of Stacks using Linked List. Where am I going wrong?

Tags: c, linked-list, stack, singly-linked-list

This is the code I've written in C :

```
#include<stdio.h>
struct Node
{
    int info;
    struct Node *next;
};
void init_Node(struct Node *n)
{
    n->next = NULL;
}
struct Node *front = NULL;
void display()
{
    struct Node *rear = front;
    if(rear == NULL)
        printf("List is empty!\n");
    else
    {
        printf("[%i]-->",rear->info);
        rear = rear->next;
    }
    printf("NULL");
    printf("\n");
}
void addEnd(int x)
{
    struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *rear = front;
    n->info = x;
    if(front == NULL)
        front = n;
    else
    {
        while(rear->next != NULL)
            rear = rear->next;
        rear->next = n;
        rear = n;
    }
    display();
}
void deleteEnd()
{
    struct Node *rear = front;
    if(front == NULL)
        printf("Stack is Empty!");
    else
    {
        while(rear->next->next != NULL)
        {
            rear = rear->next;
        }
        printf("Popped : %i\n", rear->next->info);
        rear->next = NULL;
        display();
    }
}
int main()
{
    struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    init_Node(n);
    clrscr();
    addEnd(23);
    addEnd(45);
    addEnd(8);
    addEnd(57);
    deleteEnd();
    addEnd(98);
    deleteEnd();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

The below output is the output when the implementation was done in C++ using classes.
The output for the program was supposed to be this -

[image]

but the output of my code is this - 
[image]

**EDIT**
After adding the while() loop and adding n->next = NULL; the output comes out to be : 
[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `display()` does not contain a loop, so it cannot display more than one node.

Comment: Trying to use a single-linked list structure that is a queue by definition as a stack.  Not aparrently doing any debugging.  Probably other stuff.

Comment: I don't understand why these two prototypes `void addBegin(int); void addEnd(int);` are declared in the body of `main()` and anyway `addBegin()` isn't even implemented or called.

Comment: What is `void addBegin(int)` and `void addEnd(int)`?.

Comment: sorry! Those were prototypes to the functions I previously wrote, there updated!

Comment: `n->info = x;` --> `n->info = x;n->next=NULL;` The `next` of the new node must be initialized with NULL.

Comment: @Wimmel:Yes! The loop was missing, but still the output isn't quite correct.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY:added the ouput after your suggestion.

Comment: Perhaps change is incorrect.

Comment: My bad! Made a silly mistake! instead of "=", I wrote n->next - NULL

Comment: also `deleteEnd` is wrong. It is not possible to pop all elements. and cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

You need two changes:

```
void display()
{
    struct Node *rear = front;
    if(rear == NULL)
        printf("List is empty!\n");
    else
    {
        // CHANGE 1: You need a while loop here
        while(rear != NULL) {
            printf("[%i]-->",rear->info);
            rear = rear->next;
        }
    }
    printf("NULL");
    printf("\n");
}

void addEnd(int x)
{
    struct Node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    struct Node *rear = front;
    n->info = x;
    // CHANGE 2: You need to clear n->next to NULL.
    n->next = NULL;
    if(front == NULL)
        front = n;
    else
    {
        while(rear->next != NULL)
            rear = rear->next;
        rear->next = n;
        rear = n;
    }
    display();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your function, addEnd() you need to initialize the next pointer to zero. So, right after the line    n->info = x; add a line n->next = 0;

Comment: @BLUEPIXY was just ahead of you.

Comment: did that,but still the first 2 iterations are correct but after then the ouputs are garbage I guess, don't understand why!

Comment: @WeatherVane, yes. Just noticed that . I upvoted his comment.

Comment: @Sidsec9 also in addEnd() I think that the line   rear = n; at the bottom of the else is a mistake. Try removing that line.